# Opencart Version 4 adding to cart gives json response

Tags: php, opencart

I recently installed `Open Cart Version 4.0` and every thing was successful, However, when try to add a product to the cart it gives a `json` response in a text form, it does not go to the page that I was in before adding the product.

Below I have mentioned the response that is displayed in the browser.

```
{"success":"Success: You have added <a href=\"https:\/\/stores.justgoonline.online\/index.php?route=product\/product&amp;language=en-gb&amp;product_id=40\">iPhone<\/a> to your <a href=\"https:\/\/stores.justgoonline.online\/index.php?route=checkout\/cart&amp;language=en-gb\">shopping cart<\/a>!"}
```

I have to press the back button on browser to get back to where i was.

Any fixes to this please?

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck in figuring this out. so reverted back to php 7.4 from 8.1 and downgraded opencart for version 3.x and now all working fine.